# Search the workbook using the information in a cell

Tags: vba, excel

I currently have a worksheet of data and my objective is to pick out the relevant data and summarize it. I've gone about this by creating worksheets depending on the code ID (in this scenario I'm using names), name the worksheet after the code ID and copy and send all the specific code ID's to their worksheet. Then, insert a new column, and insert a formula to get the relevant data. Create a "Summary sheet" and only have the Code ID in one column and the relevant information beside it. I'm having difficulty with pulling the information back to the summary page, in Module6, bottom. I was hoping that instead of saying the specific worksheet in this case worksheet "David", `.Range("B1").Value = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Worksheets("David").Range("B:B"))` I could have the worksheet name read from the cell beside it, so that the data will always match up.
Thanks in advance.

```
Private Sub Button2_Click()

Dim LR As Long
Dim LG As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim vcol, i As Integer
Dim icol As Long
Dim myarr As Variant
Dim title As String
Dim titlerow As Integer

    Call First  'Module1    -   Deletes irrelevant Rows and Columns from the "Data" Worksheet.

    Call Second 'Module2    -   Moves rows to new worksheet depending on their IW code and renames the worksheet as the code.

    Call Third  'Module3    -   Inserts a new column in every worksheet with the exception of Command and Data.

    Call Fourth 'Module4    -   Inserts a formula, to calculate SOMTHING, in the every row of the new column created by the third call.

    Call Fifth  'Module5    -   Creates new worksheet, "Summary", to display a summary of the data.

    Call Sixth  'Module6    -   Sums the new column and displays the results in the summary sheet.

End Sub

Sub First()


Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    With Worksheets("Data")
        .Rows("1:2").Delete         'Deletes first two rows
        .Columns("A:A").Delete      'Deletes column A
        .Rows("1:1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireColumn.Delete     'Deletes entire column where there is a blank cell in the first row
    .Columns("B:B").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete     'Deletes entire row where there is a blank cell in the column B
    End With
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub

Sub Second()

vcol = 1
Set ws = Sheets("Data")
LR = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, vcol).End(xlUp).Row
title = "A1:C1"
titlerow = ws.Range(title).Cells(1).Row
icol = ws.Columns.Count
ws.Cells(1, icol) = "Unique"

For i = 2 To LR
    On Error Resume Next
        If ws.Cells(i, vcol) <> "" And Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(ws.Cells(i, vcol), ws.Columns(icol), 0) = 0 Then
            ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, icol).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = ws.Cells(i, vcol)
        End If
Next

myarr = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ws.Columns(icol).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants))
ws.Columns(icol).Clear

For i = 2 To UBound(myarr)
    ws.Range(title).AutoFilter field:=vcol, Criteria1:=myarr(i) & ""
        If Not Evaluate("=ISREF('" & myarr(i) & "'!A1)") Then
            Sheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = myarr(i) & ""
        Else
            Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Move After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
        End If
            ws.Range("A" & titlerow & ":A" & LR).EntireRow.Copy Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Range("A1")
            Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Columns.AutoFit
Next

ws.AutoFilterMode = False
ws.Activate

End Sub

Sub Third()

'Inserts a new column in every worksheet with the exception of Command and Data.
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws.Name <> "Command" And ws.Name <> "Data" Then
        ws.Range("B:B").EntireColumn.Insert
    End If
Next ws

End Sub

Sub Fourth()
'Inserts a formula, to calculate the product of two cells, located in the new column
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws.Name <> "Command" And ws.Name <> "Data" Then
        LG = Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        ws.Range("B2:B" & LG).Formula = "=C2*D2"
    End If
Next ws

End Sub

Sub Fifth()

'Creates new worksheet, "Summary", to display a summary of the data.
With ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = .Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(2), Count:=1)
    ws.Name = "Summary"
End With

'Lists the names of each worksheet
x = 1
Sheets("Summary").Range("A:A").Clear

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws.Name <> "Command" And ws.Name <> "Data" And ws.Name <> "Summary" Then
        Sheets("Summary").Cells(x, 1) = ws.Name
        x = x + 1
    End If
Next ws

End Sub

Sub Sixth()

'Sums the new column and displays the results in the summary sheet
With Sheets("Summary")
        .Range("B1").Value = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Worksheets("David").Range("B:B"))
        .Range("B2").Value = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Worksheets("Michael").Range("B:B"))
        .Range("B3").Value = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Worksheets("Paul").Range("B:B"))
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need just to sum B:B columns in all worksheets, you could use object loop:

```
Sub Sixth()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim cnt As Long
'Sums the new column and displays the results in the summary sheet

cnt = 1
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws.Name <> "Command" And ws.Name <> "Data" And ws.Name <> "Summary" Then
        With Sheets("Summary")
                .Range("B" & cnt).Value = WorksheetFunction.Sum(ws.Range("B:B"))
        End With
        cnt = cnt + 1
    End If
Next ws
End Sub
```

I think, however that you could do it in the Fifth() subroutine. Something like:

```
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
If ws.Name <> "Command" And ws.Name <> "Data" And ws.Name <> "Summary" Then
    Sheets("Summary").Cells(x, 1) = ws.Name
    Sheets("Summary").Cells(x, 2) = WorksheetFunction.Sum(ws.Range("B:B"))
    x = x + 1
End If
Next ws
```